# Expandeble menu using sliding menu

Tags: android, menu, expand, slidingmenu

I want to implement sliding menu in my application with some different requirment.I got the working sample for simple sliding menu and it just works fine.

But i want to implement expandable menu using sliding menu.In which when user selects main menu then submenu appears below it and menu expands itself so that user can scroll down to see other menu too (Same as expandable listview).

[image]

How can i do it? Please help me!

Comment: What are you asking? Just put an expandable list view as the view in the navigation drawer

Comment: i did exactly,but its not working!

Comment: What isn't working? Please describe more

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library for your sliding menu:
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

It allows you to have any arbitrary ViewGroup inside it instead of just single menu items. This means you can add any type of Layout, Views , ListViews etc in your side menu. You can include an expandable ListView here and it should work just fine.